# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'utf' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home2/champio1/public_html/includes/config.php on line 16

Tags: php, utf-8, syntax

this code was developed in config.php file but it gives that........
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'utf' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home2/champio1/public_html/includes/config.php on line 16
i.e   meta charset="utf-8" />

---

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "champio1_EyeLion";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "champio1_database";

$con = @mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password","$db_name");

if(!$con)
{
echo"
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>

<center>    
<br>
<br>
<br>        <h1>Coming Soon - سيتم تشغيل الموقع قريبا </h1>



</html>";
exit;
}

$DomainUrl = "http://joglobe.com";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes inside the HTML you're trying to echo break the string. You could try to escape them, but using a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) would be so much simpler:

```
$comingSoon = <<< 'COMING_SOON'
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>

<center>    
<br>
<br>
<br>        <h1>Coming Soon - سيتم تشغيل الموقع قريبا </h1>



</html>
COMING_SOON;

echo $comingSoon;
```

Comment: With over 100k reputation I think you should know how many duplicates there exist for this kind of question and that you can vote to close them.

Comment: Thanks a lot  it worked partially but when get http://joglobe.com//signup many errors appeared....... Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home2/champio1/public_html/includes/account.function.php on line 98

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home2/champio1/public_html/includes/account.function.php on line 99

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home2/champio1/public_html/includes/account.function.php on line 41

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes embedded in a string in double quotes. This makes the PHP interpreter think you're done with your string, so it expects the next thing to be probably a semicolon. 
 You need to escape the double quotes, like this `\"`

In other words, replace all instances of `"` in the text you want to echo with `\"` and you'll be fine.

For instance:

```
echo "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">"
```